# React-Router: How to replace this calls in the Route callbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When setting a react-router app, I often set it on callbacks to represent authorization filters. this leads me to such designs:

```
# before, in my root component
requireAuth() { ... }
noAuth() { ... }
render() {
  return (
    <Router history={this.props.history}>
      <Route path='/' component={App} onEnter={this.requireAuth}>
        <Route path='toys' component={Toys}/>
        ...
      <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} onEnter={this.noAuth}>
        ...
    </Router>
  )
}
```

I am now trying to port this to nodejs and render the page in the server. Suddenly, I'm asked to group all the routes in a const. Second, I lose my root component and those `this.` callback binds, and am not able to recreate the same architecture on the server.

So my first problem is the route. In react, I can't return groups of components, but a component which encapsulates all the rest. So, this was my attempt:

```
# root component render
# after import routes from './routes'
render() {
  return (
    <Router routes={routes} history={this.props.history}/>
  );
}
# in routes.js
module.exports = (
  <Route> # is this right?
    <Route path='/' component={App} onEnter={this.requireAuth}>
      <Route path='toys' component={Toys}/>
      ...
    <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} onEnter={this.noAuth}>
      ...
  </Route>
```

So, this doesn't seem to cut it and I get a few errors. First, I'm encapsulating all routes inside a main `Route` component. Is this correct, from a react-router perspective? Can I have kind of empty-encapsulating components?

Second would be: How do I bind those `this.` callbacks on the server side now? Since I'm following the tutorials, My express router looks smth like this:

```
import routes from './src/components/routes';
...
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
....
```

But it's breaking with:

```
onEnter: undefined.requireAuth,
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'requireAuth' of undefined
```

Which is right, as routes constant is not bound to any context.

Or is there a more proper way to do this in react-router, and binding callbacks to routes is the wrong approach?